# Onemesh or similar with hostapd

Tags: wireless-networking, ip, hostapd, mesh-networking

I've learned about TP-Link's proprietary Onemesh technology that, as far as I understand, allows to combine multiple WiFi access points into one single access point.

While that can be achieved by giving all access points the same SSID, clients might still to switch from one AP to another, causing overhead.

Onemesh seems to give all APs the same MAC address and synchronizes connection information between APs, so the client cannot differentiate between APs.

Can the same be achieved by using hostapd or openWRT? I imagine having multiple Raspberry Pis connected via LAN with hostapd running on each, while the clients only see one single AP and don't have to switch back and forth between them. The Pis will have to synchronize connection information between each other when a client connects and figure out which PI is the closest to each client.

Comment: Can you share your sources? I'm not familiar with Onemesh, but I'm skeptical about your interpretation. It's more likely that what you read is a marketing speak for multiple APs having the same SSID + 802.11r + 802.11k and maybe something on top of it. In other words: the same thing all meshes are supposed to achieve, but with a fancy name.

Comment: ahh thanks, I learned about 802.11r and k...